# Hibernate not save Entity to oracle db

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, struts2

I made a small crud app using struts2,spring,hibernate with oracle db.
action class add methos is this.

```
public String addorgs() throws Exception {

    t.setAO_CreatedBy("me");
    t.setAO_Name("ok");

    orgdao.addOrg(t);

    // emplist = empdao.showEmployuee();
    return SUCCESS;

}
```

Entity class for test:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test")
public class Test {



@Id
@Column(name = "AO_ID")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SequenceIdGenerator", sequenceName = "SEQ_AT_ORGANISATION",allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SequenceIdGenerator")
private int AO_ID;

@Column(name = "AO_Name")
private String AO_Name;

@Column(name = "AO_CreatedBy")
private String AO_CreatedBy;



public int getAO_ID() {
    return AO_ID;
}

public void setAO_ID(int aO_ID) {
    AO_ID = aO_ID;
}

public String getAO_Name() {
    return AO_Name;
}

public void setAO_Name(String aO_Name) {
    AO_Name = aO_Name;
}

public String getAO_CreatedBy() {
    return AO_CreatedBy;
}

public void setAO_CreatedBy(String aO_CreatedBy) {
    AO_CreatedBy = aO_CreatedBy;
}

}
```

DAO method :

```
public void addOrg(Test t) {
    //System.out.println("save : "+org);
    Session session = null;

    session = sessionfactory.openSession();

    try {
        System.out.println("before save : "+t.getAO_ID());  
        session.save(t);
    System.out.println("after save : "+t.getAO_ID());   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I didn't get any errors and data is not go to db. I test this code with mysql and it works fine. I think problem is with sequence.
out put is like this.

```
 before save : 0
```

Hibernate:

```
select
    SEQ_AT_ORGANISATION.nextval 
from
    dual
```

after save : 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try

```
public void addOrg(Test t) {
    //System.out.println("save : "+org);
    Session session = sessionfactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx;
    try {
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         session.save(t);
         tx.commit();
    System.out.println("after save : "+t.getAO_ID());   
    } catch (Exception e) {
       if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
     session.close();
     }
```

Comment: Works fine.
Thanks for help in short time.